# Prevent to open via Window.open more than one time

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular12

I have a button.

```
<button (click)="bxs()">

    <span>BXS</span>
</button>
```

my TS:

```
 bxs(): void {
   
    window.open(url, "bxs");
  }
```

how to show a error message where it's already open
Example:

If I already click the button to open then it has to show a error message

I tried this with `sessionStorage`

`sessionStorage.setItem('BXD', 'true');`

but it doesn't detect if the URL opened is closed or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the opened page part of the same application or is it at least served from the same origin? If not, there is most probably no way for the opener to get any information about that page.

Comment: the same navigator

Comment: you need to assign a **counter**

Comment: and when it close how to reset the counter ?

Comment: And what is supposed to happen if user navigates to given URL "manually", i.e. enters the URL in location bar?

Comment: they can't enter url manually: the url is very long and its just for limit pers

Comment: [Here's an example](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/components/social-logins/base-login.component.ts#L44)

Comment: @Pieterjan thank you for sharing this solution but in Edge doesn't work 
any ideas ?

Comment: bxs(): void {
  const bxsWindow = window.open(url, "bxs");
  if (bxsWindow === null) {
    // show error message
    console.log("BXD window is already open.");
  }
}